# How can I filter parts of a SpatialPolygonDataFrame?

Tags: r, rgdal, r-sp

I would like if there is a simple solution to filter a SpatialPolygonDataFrame in R. Imagine I have many polygons but I only want to select some of them to plot them using `leaflet`

My data comes from [data.gouv.fr](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/contours-iris/)

Here is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/pachevalier/8bc7e6dfbb33f5e956b1) for loading the data into R.

If I want to draw only one polygon in `leaflet`, I filter the `@data` part of my SpatialPolygonDataFrame, get the id

```
> ign_shape_iris@data %>% 
+   filter(DCOMIRIS == "606120301")
 DEPCOM NOM_COM IRIS  DCOMIRIS               NOM_IRIS TYP_IRIS  id 
1  60612  Senlis 0301 606120301 Vald'Aunette-Gateliere        H 790
```

Then I plot only the polygon I want :

```
leaflet(ign_shape_iris@polygons[[790]]) %>% 
 addTiles() %>%
 addPolygons()
```

I'm sure there is a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try treating it as a usual data.frame, and think subset instead of filter:

```
ign_shape_iris[ign_shape_iris$DCOMIRIS == "606120301",]
```

or

```
subset(ign_shape_iris, DCOMIRIS == "606120301")
```